# MacOS Ventura 13.3 apps don't show in Camera and Microphone Privacy & Security settings

Tags: system-settings, camera, privacy, microphone, macos

I've been having issues getting apps to show in System Settings > Privacy & Security > Microphone & Camera, on MacOS Ventura 13.3.

I have a iMac 27-inch, Late 2013, which I used OpenCore Patcher to get the latest operating system working (required for my work).

I tried all solutions in this video and nothing worked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD-IF38E3Kw

However, I did find this solution that worked for Microphone on Stack Exchange:
[Solution if you are running Monterey 12.2.1 and BigSur 11.7.4 and Ventura 13.3](https://superuser.com/a/1755116/1795446)

I'm unsure how to get a similar solution working for Camera. Here's the Microphone solution:

In Terminal, open the TCC database by running:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db
```

Add app by using:

```
insert into access
values 
('kTCCServiceMicrophone','<AppBundleURLname>', 0, 2, 2, 1, null, null, null, 'UNUSED', null, null, 1669648527);
```

Then close the connection to the database using:

```
.quit
```

Thanks to @Kubuntuer82 for providing the Microphone solution

Comment: This is rooted in the fact that the security perms don't work when SIP is off & that you need SIP off to run an OpenCore OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this great tool on GitHub which makes the process easier for Microphone and Camera permissions: https://github.com/jslegendre/tccplus

I found it in this article: https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXTweaks/comments/fnw67y/release_tccplus_grantremove_accessibility/

Answer (score 4):

Download the following file and save it in your downloads folder GitHub Link: https://github.com/jslegendre/tccplus/releases/tag/1.0

Follow these steps:

1. Locate the app folder in Finder that contains the app for which you need to assign permissions.
2. Open  Terminal, type the command `codesign -dr -` and drag the app file from Finder into the Terminal window.
3. Press Enter. Terminal will display the path to the app along with other details, including its identifier.

Example: `codesign -dr - /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app`
Take note of the app's identifier (e.g., `com.microsoft.teams`).

4. In Terminal, enter the following commands:

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/
    chmod +x tccplus
    ./tccplus add Microphone [identifier]
   ```

Replace "[identifier]" with the app's identifier you noted earlier.
Example: `./tccplus add Microphone com.microsoft.teams`

5. Press Enter. Terminal will confirm the successful addition of permissions.

To grant camera access as well, repeat the previous command, replacing "Microphone" with "Camera".

The answer is based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1779925/macos-ventura-cant-give-permissions-opencore).

Comment: AWESOME! Saved my life dude! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Sonoma I found there are four additional values that need to be added to the values list (I needed it so JupyterLab could access mic & camera):

```
insert into access 
values 
('kTCCServiceCamera', 'org.jupyter.jupyterlab-desktop', 0, 2, 2, 1, null, null, null, 'UNUSED', null, null, 1669648527, 0, 0, 'UNUSED', 0);

insert into access 
values 
('kTCCServiceMicrophone', 'org.jupyter.jupyterlab-desktop', 0, 2, 2, 1, null, null, null, 'UNUSED', null, null, 1669648527, 0, 0, 'UNUSED', 0);
```

Also, one should really make sure to take a backup of TCC.db before attempting ANY of this, as in:

`cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db ~/TCC.db.bak`

from one's $HOME directory.